# Throwing "unexpected token" error, when i use jsop api in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

When i used to fetch data from json api its throwing "Unexpected token" error. Below, i've added my code what i have tried so far. Get me out from this issue. I'm trying to solve this problem long time.

Here,

```
var Demo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        getInitialState:function(){
            return {
                data:[]
            };
        },
        componentDidMount: function () {
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"
            }).done(function(data) {
              this.setState({data: data})
            });
        },
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.data.map(function(el,i) {
                    return <div key={i}>
                        <div>{el.Name}</div>
                        <div>{el.City}</div>
                        <div>{el.Country}</div>
                    </div>;
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Stream = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="scrollContent ">
                <Demo />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors in your code

1. move `getInitialState` and `componentDidMount` from `render` method, these methods should be as children of your component (`Demo`) class but not as children of `render` method
2. add `dataType: 'json'` to `$.ajax`, because now it returns string, but in your case you need get `json`
3. as you are using `this.setState` in `.done` you should set `this` to `.done` callback, because now `this` refers to `$.ajax` object not `Demo`, you can use `.bind` method to do it.
4. change `this.props.data` to `this.state.data` because data located in state object not in props
5. array with data located in `records` property use it instead of just `data`

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/24678/)

```
var Demo = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function() {
    return {
      data :[]
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php",
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {
      this.setState({ data: response.records });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    var customers = this.state.data.map(function(el,i) {
      return <div key={i}>
        <div>{el.Name}</div>
        <div>{el.City}</div>
        <div>{el.Country}</div>
      </div>
    });

    return <div>{ customers }</div>;
  }
});
```

Comment: great explanation and great contribution ..rocking

Comment: @Alexander. Thank u bro.